# Re-positioning data frame row based on some criteria

Tags: r

I have a very large data set that I want to re-position some values of the data frame based on some conditions, see below the example of what I want to achieve, for instance let say I have the data frame below

```
V01 V02 V03 V04 V05 V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
12  NA  NA  NA  NA  2   NA  NA  NA  NA
23  4   NA  NA  NA  3   5   NA  NA  NA
16  NA  NA  NA  NA  7   NA  NA  NA  NA
25  5   6   NA  NA  2   19  10  NA  NA
21  14  NA  NA  NA  1   5   NA  NA  NA
```

for each of the V0's there is corresponding V's value but the problem is that the V1 to V5 values are based on the ascending order of the values from V01 to V05. for example in row 2, the corresponding value for V01 answer (23) is V2 Answer(5) while the corresponding value for V02 Answer(4) is V1 Answer(3).

Also in Row 4, the corresponding value for V01 Answer(25) is V03 Answer(10), while the corresponding value for V02 Answer(5) is V1 Answer(2) and the corresponding Answer for V03 Answer(6) is V1 Answer(19).

Definitely there won't be any problem with rows with only one value. like row 1 and 3

What I want to achieve is to re-position V1 to V5 based on their corresponding values of V01 to V05. See below what the output of the example should look like

```
V01 V02 V03 V04 V05 V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
12  NA  NA  NA  NA  2   NA  NA  NA  NA
23  4   NA  NA  NA  5   3   NA  NA  NA
16  NA  NA  NA  NA  7   NA  NA  NA  NA
25  5   6   NA  NA  10  2   19  NA  NA
21  14  NA  NA  NA  5   1   NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: Sorry I mean that What I want to achieve is to re-position V1 to V5 based on their corresponding values of V01 to V05.

Comment: Edit your question - the comments can not format code properly.

Comment: Can you explain why in the fourth line, `(V1, V2, V3)` is `(10, 2, 19)` and not `(19, 10, 2)`? I think I don't understand the logic of how to rearrange the data. I initially thought you want to change the ordering based on the value (see my answer below) but it seems like I was wrong. I leave my answer for the time being in case I can adjust it, else I will remove it later.

Comment: In row 4, for the V0's, 5<6<25, which means the corresponding  value for 5 in V1's is 2 i. e the first value  and the corresponding value for 6 in V1's is 19 i. e the second value and while the corresponding  value for 25 is 10 and to rearrange in the order that we have in V0(25, 5, 6) then we have V1(10,2,19)

Comment: My output is correct which means the above did not answer it

Comment: To clarify, how would (V01, V02, V03) in row 4 have to look so that (V1, V2, V3) should be (19, 10, 2)?

Comment: it is the other way round, V01 to V05 are fixed, they cannot be changed, it is only V1 to V5 we want to rearrange. for row 4, (V01, V02, V03) = (25,5,6) then is corresponding V1's will be arranged to (V1, V2, V3) = (10,2,19)

Comment: Yes, I get that the first ones are fixed, but I do not understand how (25, 5, 6) informs you that the order of the second should be (10, 2, 19), why not (2, 10, 19) or (19, 10, 2) or (10, 2, 19). The mapping is still unclear to me.

Comment: Initially this what we have

Comment: Initially this what we have (25, 5,6) and (2,19,10).  then 5 maps 2, 6 maps 19, while 25 maps 10. based the arrangement is based on the ascending order of (25, 5, 6). The first value in V1's maps the lowest in V0's, the second value in V1's maps the second lowest in V0's while the third value maps the highest in V0's. therefore to arrange the map, therefore the correct arrangement that will ensure one to one mapping (25,5,6) maps (10,2,19)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

df
  V01 V02 V03 V04 V05 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  12  NA  NA  NA  NA  2 NA NA NA NA
2  23   4  NA  NA  NA  3  5 NA NA NA
3  16  NA  NA  NA  NA  7 NA NA NA NA
4  25   5   6  NA  NA  2 19 10 NA NA
5  21  14  NA  NA  NA  1  5 NA NA NA

df$rows <- 1:nrow(df) # to keep row order
```

The following could be written in one long pipe, but for readability, I break it into several lines:

```
df <- melt(df, id.vars = c("rows", paste0("V0", 1:5)))
df <- df %>% group_by(V01) %>% arrange(desc(value))
df <- df %>% group_by(V01)  %>% mutate(ind = paste0("V", 1:n()))
df <- df %>% dcast(rows + V01 + V02 + V03 + V05 + V05 ~ ind, value.var = "value", fill = NA)
df$rows <- NULL

df
  V01 V02 V03 V05 V05 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  12  NA  NA  NA  NA  2 NA NA NA NA
2  23   4  NA  NA  NA  5  3 NA NA NA
3  16  NA  NA  NA  NA  7 NA NA NA NA
4  25   5   6  NA  NA 19 10  2 NA NA
5  21  14  NA  NA  NA  5  1 NA NA NA
```

Comment: With the above example, I realize that the order of the rows have changed, for example row 3 is now in row 2 for the output, is there a way I can still keep the same order of the rows for the output  data frame?

Comment: Please see my comment on your question. If your desired output is correct, this does not answer your question. Can you clarify my question above?

Comment: In any case @Dare, I have adjusted the code to retain the row ordering.

Comment: Row 4 should be 10, 2, 19. See my answer  to the question you first asked,  in each row, the values in V1's were based on the ascending order of the values in V0's And i only needed to reposition the values of V1's based on the current order of V0's not based on the ascending order, the 2, 19 ,10 in V1 is for 5, 6, 25 in V0, then to get 25, 5, 6 then V1 should be arranged to 10, 2, 19